Installing pytorch on jetson tx2

Nvidia jeston TX2
jetpack 4.6.5
L4T Version 32.7.5
Python 3.6.9
ubuntu 18.04

When I am trying to install torch 1.11 but it is installing torch 1.8.0. I have created a virtual environment also.
Before installing I tried following commands
pip3 uninstall torch 

pip3 cache purge

Installing torch 1.11
I am trying to install pytorch from below link
https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/pytorch-version-for-jetpack-4-6-5-l4t-32-7-5/303744
wget https://nvidia.box.com/shared/static/p57jwntv436lfrd78inwl7iml6p13fzh.whl -O torch-1.11.0a0+17540c5+nv22.01-cp36-cp36m-linux_aarch64.whl

pip3 install numpy torch-1.11.0a0+17540c5+nv22.01-cp36-cp36m-linux_aarch64.whl

Processing ./torch-1.11.0a0+17540c5+nv22.01-cp36-cp36m-linux_aarch64.whl
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in ./myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (1.19.5)
Requirement already satisfied: dataclasses in ./myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from torch==1.11.0a0+17540c5+nv22.01) (0.8)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions in ./myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from torch==1.11.0a0+17540c5+nv22.01) (4.1.1)
Installing collected packages: torch
Successfully installed torch-1.8.0

Successfully installed torch 1.8.0

ubuntu 18.04 has no more support that's why you have such an old version of python. that's probably why you can't install torch > 1.8

I have to install torch 1.11 which i believe is less than 1.8.0

Thanks for clarifying me (1.11>1.8.0), so what is the possible solution now?

updating your system is one solution. maybe there are other solutions but i think this would be better answered on askubuntu

But I think I cannot update the system because L4t version 32.7.5 comes with ubuntu 18.04.. I had asked this question in Nvidia platform but got no response from them. Don't why?

i don't know what l4t is, but it seems you're not getting what "unsupported" means. nvidia denied you support because your system is unsupported. this will happen all along the way, look at how i'm the only one answering you in such a crowded place as stack overflow. either you're an expert and you can solve this alone, or you update your system

Hey there, first of all, don't use the python version which has no official support anymore. I can help you with jetson related issues but as @folengateis suggested askubuntu is better to look for solutions. The best way forward is to upgrade Ubuntu version of your Jetson. It will also upgrade your L4T version (linux kernel version)
